# How to make a static image-button turn sides?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

I'm newbie to programming. In drum app trying to make a cymbal turn left when you hit it on the left side, turn right when you hit it on the right side and so on. What action do I need?
Thanks a lot.

Comment: What have you tried? How are you constructing your UI? The best thing to do is to tell us what you are doing, how you are going about it, and what is not working for you. Then you will get better answers.

Comment: Well,what I really wanna do is when you touch (hit) the cymbal in the left side to turn left, just like in the photo I made in the photoshop.When you touch the right side to turn right and before it returns to the original position to do 2-3 small rebounds, just like in real life.I've tried MakeRotation, MakeTranslation but its not really what I want. Thanks

Comment: I am sorry I am not allowed to post images yet...

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to rotate the image, you'll need something along the lines of:

```
myImageView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI * 0.1);
```

Comment: Thanks Eric, I 've tried MakeRotation but the whole image rotates.What I really want is something like this:Suppose you have a pen balancing on your finger and every time you touch the left side is going down (the right side up) and then returns to the original position. I made photo in photoshop but I am not allowed to post images.